# Jquery Validation File size validation rule

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

If the file size is more than 2MB or less than 2mb
it always display File size more than 2mb

```
<script>
$.validator.addMethod('filesize', function(value, element, param) {

    var param = 2000;
    // element = element to validate (<input>)
    // value = value of the element (file name)

    return this.optional(element) || (element.files[0].size <= param)    
});

$("#dealDetails").validate({

    rules   : {
    "dealcatg"  : {
        required: true
    },

    "deal_image":{
        required : true,
        accept   : "image/*",
        filesize : true,
    }
});
</script>
```

Its always return false.

Comment: you return value in `or` condition, can you return value in  separate and then check? `return this.optional(element);` `console.log(element.files[0].size)`

Comment: Make that console log on `element.files[0].size` as Prashant sugested and come back with the news please

Answer (score 1):

You can add a jquery validation method like shown below

jQuery.validator.addMethod("checksize", function (val, element) {

```
      var size = element.files[0].size;
        console.log(size);

       if (size > 2*1048576)// checks the file more than 1 MB
       {
           console.log("returning false");
            return false;
       } else {
           console.log("returning true");
           return true;
       }

  }, "File type error");
```

and use it like below

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#form').validate({
  rules: {
       image: {
          required: true,
          extension:'jpe?g,png',
          checksize:true,
          }
         }
      });
   });
```

Try this..